# Projecting the raster and vector to the same place

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have 3 groups of raster layers all in the same place, but my group with my vector layer are located above... I am working in QGIS.

They all have the same CRS WGS 84 / EPSG Greenland Polar Stereographic, EPSG:5938.

The project, each vector layer and raster layer have the same CRS.

Why are they not on the same position and how do i get them to be that?

[image]

Comment: Please check, whether the CRS of the shapefile really is the same, or if you forced it. Also, please don't double post your questions, but edit the existing one, thank you.

Comment: raster or vector is wrong. You should see the bounding boxen in the "Layer Properties". Do you have the correct coordinate of one point inside greenland for comparsion?

Comment: I think the other question is (slightly) better so I have switched the duplication